# debugging errors when you have document split into multiple files?

Tags: emacs, latex

Sometimes I construct a LaTeX document by breaking it up in sections and calling `\input` from the main file. When I do this, debugging becomes difficult because when I compile it with `latex` or `pdflatex`, it will give me the location of the error in terms of global line numbers rather than line numbers in the offending document. Is there a good way to work with or around that? In LaTeX, or in Emacs, possibly?

Comment: when you navigate errors with (C-c n, i think) emacs + auctex, at least for me, it opens the offending file and moves to the current line. That works for me with emacsW32 on windows, carbon emacs on os x, and gnu emacs + auctex on linux.

Comment: Oh... AucTeX. Forgot about that. I just installed it and it seems to be the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Texclipse helps find "bad" places, but this is not a command line tool.

http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/